# How can I use dynamodb locally without expensive metrics getting created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Dynamodb local to run about 12 tables locally on a server on Azure.

I have the region set to us-west-2 and this is needed for my code to work, however this results in metrics getting created on my AWS account in the us-west-2 region.

These metrics cost me upwards of $120 last month for running dynamodb locally!

How can I get rid of them?

Here's a screenshot of the metrics on my AWS dashboard

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the dynamodb local? You need to set the endpoint (http://localhost:8000) in config. If you dont set the endpoint, it would use the remote dynamodb.

Comment: I'm 100% sure I'm using localhost, I don't see the tables in us-west or any other region.

Comment: I am not sure what metrics got generated and whether it is related to dynamodb or some other service that you are using? Did you check whether you are setting the localhost endpoint? What do you mean by "locally on a server on Azure"?

Comment: I run dynamodb locally via Docker running on an azure vm, I've added an image of the metrics to the question. I have 11 tables on AWS proper and have 1 local db that I make all changes to and run the cross regional replication lib on that, it then in turn creates the cross region replication tables with long names

Comment: Do you have any global tables created in Dynamodb which does cross region replication? https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/

Comment: I'm familiar with them but they're only available in 5 regions, my app needs to run in 11

Comment: I am just trying to workout the reason for cross region replication and metrics generated for it above. The question is whether you have any global tables created in your account or not?

Comment: @notionquest no, not at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163962/discussion-between-jonathan-and-notionquest).

Answer (score 0):

The metrics were created by the cross region replication library. The solution according to the docs at https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library was to pass `--dontPublishCloudwatch` as an argument.